# Dart - Get next element inside a for-loop

Tags: for-loop, dart

I am using this for-loop:

```
for (var elem in sortedTokens){
    if (elem.identifier == "ACCESSOR"){
      //
    }
    else if (elem.identifier == "PROPERTY"){
      // Check the identifier of the next element  
    }
 }
```

How am I able to access the next element inside of it? Until now, I've always used a while loop with an index in Dart. What is the correct way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use a regular for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedTokens.length; i++){
    var elem = sortedTokens[i];
    if (elem.identifier == "ACCESSOR"){
      //
    }
    else if (elem.identifier == "PROPERTY"){
      if (i+1 < sortedTokens.length) {
          var nextElem = sortedTokens[i+1];
          // Check the identifier of the next element 
      }
    }
}
```

But you could take it one step further and wrap that functionality:

```
void forEach<T>(List<T> list, void action(T current, T next)) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    T current = list[i];
    T next = i+1 < list.length ? list[i+1] : null;
    action(current, next);
  }
}

forEach (sortedTokens, (elem, next) {
    if (elem.identifier == "ACCESSOR"){
      //
    }
    else if (elem.identifier == "PROPERTY"){
        if (next != null) {
            // Check the identifier of the next element 
        }
    }
});
```

---

> Working [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/96ce48f6baf2d28bc8fc614c42444f62#consoletab) example

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the next element of a `for-in` iteration while handling the current element. 
A `for-in` loop like `for (var elem in sortedTokens) { ... }` is roughly equivalent to:

```dart
for (var it = sortedTokens.iterator; it.moveNext();) {
   var elem = it.current;
   ...
}
```

As you can see, the `moveNext` that moves to the next element is only executed when the body for the current element has completed.

So, there is no way to do what you want with `for-in` without doing some work-around. The `for-in` is optimized for doing something for each element, not for accessing elements out of order.

The simplest work-around would be to just use indexes anyway. There's nothing wrong with that if you actually need to look ahead or behind or step quicker in some cases.

Another work-arounds could be:

```dart
bool isProperty = false;
for (var elem in sortedTokens) {
  if (isProperty) {
    // check the identifier of the current element
    isProperty = false;
    continue;
  }
  if (elem.identifier == "ACCESSOR") { 
    //
  } else if (elem.identifier == "PROPERTY") {
    isProperty = true;
  }
}
```

This just keeps state (here it's just a single boolean) between elements, so the next element knows what you wanted to do with it.
In some cases that's useful and convenient (like building a comma-separated list, you want to special-case the first element to not add a comma), in other cases it's more trouble than it's worth because the state gets unwieldy and the logic convoluted.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer!